# Read and Write on same TcpStream in Rust

Tags: rust, buffer

I have a `TcpStream` that prints out received lines by buffering them in a `BufReader`.

```
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead, Write, BufWriter};

fn main() {
    let stream = TcpStream::connect("irc.freenode.org:6667").unwrap();
    let mut line = String::new();
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(stream);

    // let mut writer = BufWriter::new(stream);  //Issues with moved value  `stream`

    loop {
        let _ = reader.read_line(&mut line);
        println!("{}", line);
        line = String::new();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to write to the stream as well using a `BufWriter` but come across issues with `use of moved value 'stream'`.

How can I read and write on the same `TcpStream`?

I am aware of a crate that provides this functionality, but want to understand how to do it myself as I am new to Rust.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for [`BufStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.2.0/std/io/struct.BufStream.html) ?